# Header Check Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I want to reject all messages with following header:

```
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10003:dump.php(1954) : eval()'d code
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 13:28:58 +0200
From: Agnieszka Wisniewski <agnieszka_wisniewski@monasteriodelashuelgas.org>
Message-ID: <ebc99995e5cd5649c5df34833c173796@www.monasteriodelashuelgas.org>
```

I have tried with `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_check`

```
/eval()'d code/                                         REJECT SPF rule 1  
/eval()\'d code/                                            REJECT SPF rule 2
```

but it won't block emails as I expect.

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape some character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/3604386) in the pattern string, such as `*?+|()`. In this case, you forgot to escape the `(` and `)` characters. This pattern

```
/eval\(\)'d code/ REJECT SPF rule 1
```

should works in your problem above.